# Is there a way to create a tracker using Tuleap API REST?

Tags: api, tracker, tuleap

Tuleap API looks great:
https://demo.tuleap.org/api/explorer

I can find how to access projects, trackers, artifacts. I can see how to create new artifacts. But I find no way to create new trackers....

is there really no way to create a simple bug tracker from the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

By November 2019, on the [Tuleap's API Explorer](https://tuleap.net/api/explorer), the operations' list regarding trackers **doesn't show any method to add a tracker**. The API methods available on this topic are:

- Get tracker;
- Partial update of a tracker;
- Get all reports of a given tracker;
- Get all artifacts of a given tracker;
- Get all possible parent artifacts for a given tracker.

[image]